# Why is this getting so many close votes?

Tags: discussion, topics

**[How to differentiate between head voice and falsetto?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25304/is-chris-isaak-using-falsetto-voice-in-his-famous-wicked-games)**

As far as I can see it isn't off-topic; it's asking a pertinent question about a style of vocal.

It may not be the best question of all time, but it doesn't appear to be 'identifying a song' etc. It is asking a clear question about a vocal technique, using a specific example.

Maybe it just needs the 'technique' part adding into the question & the reliance on the specific example dropping into the body of the question?

Comment: I'd guess as an "analysis of a specific work" - it seems pretty dead on that imo. A better question may be "How do you identify if a singer is singing in falsetto or not?" - I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't find "analysis of a specific work" as a banned topic. I see "identifying a song, genre, instrument, etc.". Not sure if I'm not looking hard enough, but...

Comment: The close reason right below that was the one I was referring to. (I haven't voted to close yet, but it's probably better for someone else to take an attempt at edition rather than me - with my limited vocal knowledge!)

Comment: Why don't you think this is an identification question?  There is no technical question present, he just wants to know what voice the singer is using.

Comment: ... which, for a singer, is a technical question. You wouldn't believe how much I've read up about pedagogic techniques since I joined this forum... & I'm still really no wiser.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't find "analysis of a specific work" as a banned topic. I see "identifying a song, genre, instrument, etc.". Not sure if I'm not looking hard enough, but...

Asking for analysis of specific work is off topic. From the Closing Reasons popup:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Now that I look at the [Help Center - What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this closing reason isn't mentioned; this is wrong.

I can understand why you didn't see it. This should be added. You can ask a question with a [feature-request](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag to do that.

Comment: We should really clarify that close reason. We are typically ok with questions on a technique  given a specific example that can be perceive as analysis and we usually like answering questions about analysis of works as long as the user has the chords/notes/sheet music/notation needed for it. When a question is solely about _transcription_  it tends to be closed for the reason mentioned above. I think we should replace **analysis** with the word **transcription**.

Comment: @Dom Transcription is far too narrow, the close reason is indeed meant to cover analysis in general (of a work in specific).  Asking about how to play a certain note pattern, what particular markings mean, etc. using a specific passage as an example would be perfectly acceptable, however, as you say.  We mostly want to avoid identification and overly broad "How would you analyze this?" questions.

Comment: I think it's good to mention transcription in specific, however, so thanks for pointing that out.  I have updated the on-topic page linked in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should have been allowed. The question could have been edited, like suggested to "How to identify falsetto", and the example left in there. So, an edit instead of closing could have saved it without closing, and without changing any existing policies. I'll do this edit, and we'll see what happens.

Comment: There has been a long discussion about editing a question into a completely different one, where the answer is no. If OP wants to edit it into something like that, he can. Other users shouldn't change the question. (I cannot find the discussion right now)

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: I guess you mean this one: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/850/should-we-use-heavy-editing-to-generalize-questions-or-ask-new-questions-altoget. I don't know if this should be considered "heavy editing". If it's reopened, it's reopened, otherwise it will remain closed...

Comment: In this instance, after being pointed to this meta with a comment to the edit, it seems to have been well-recieved, so I think in this case we have win-win. As regards the question itself, I'd love to see a good definitive answer, because, after having been a singer [untrained] for 35 years, including several as a session singer... I still have no real clue what a 'head voice' is & only ever heard the term for the first time recently.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername I am the author of the original question and I approve this editing. ;) Thanks!